# Command that depends on another command

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dialog, dependency-properties

I spent most of today trying to make sense of the MANY different approaches to closing a dialog in WPF/MVVM. Most answers focus on simple dialogs - like a Yes/No confirmation dialog. However, no one seems to describe a more complicated case of a dialog that actually performs some actions, which have to be committed in a transactional way: all-or-nothing.

There is an OK button, clicking which invokes a bound command on the ViewModel. All is fine.

Now, I want to close the window if the command succeeds, but I don't want to close it, if the command fails.

After hours of research I came to the conclusion that apparently no one in the world has ever had a similar problem to solve :|

The solution that I invented, but have not implemented yet is as follows:

1. I would have a `ConditionalCloseWindow` command, which takes the window as a parameter and, well, closes the window.
2. The `ConditionalCloseWindow` command would have an attached property:

   ```
   public static readonly DependencyProperty Condition =
       DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Condition", typeof(ICommand), ... snip
   ```
3. Executing the `ConditionalCloseWindow` command would first cause the execution of the `Condition` command. Only on successful execution of the `Condition` command would the `ConditionalCloseWindow` actually perform the `Close()`.

What do you think of such solution? Is it totally invalid? Or maybe it is an accepted pattern, that I have not succeeded to discover through my research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way  would set up a Closing event handler in ViewModel, such as:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
<i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
    <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding WindowClosing}" />
</i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

in ViewModel:

```
public ICommand WindowClosing
{
    get
    {
        return _windowClosing ?? _windowClosing = new RelayCommand<CancelEventArgs>(
            (args) =>{
                   if(somethingDoesNotMakeSense) 
                       args.Cancel = true;
                });
    }
}
```

though this can get a little messy.

Another one I thought up;

```
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <commandCall Command="ButtonClicked" />
                <commmandCall Command="CloseWindow" Parameter="{Binding VIewModelCanWeClose}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

CloseWindow should be command, implemented in Codebehind, which will get in parameter "should we close or not" and call Close() based on it.

Comment: Not exactly what I need, but I can make it work. It is as close as it can get to an ideal solution. BTW - 'ideal' probably does not exist.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065887/how-to-bind-close-command-to-a-button

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve your problem. My first suggestion is, that your dialogs ViewModel has a property of type action. Your dialog set that property to a action that closes the dialog. In your command you can invoke that action and your dialog will close.

Answer (score 0):

There are various "Form" controls out there that allow you to orchestrate things i.e. support validation, cancel/ok logic, close, etc.

- http://dataform.codeplex.com
- http://wpfdataform.codeplex.com/ (not sure on the state of this but it's trying to copy the Silverlight DataForm).
- http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/ModalDialogs-IEditableObject-and-MVVM-in-Silverlight-4.aspx (shows you how you could structure the behaviour for a "modal" dialog...Silverlight based but should be close if not same for WPF).

You can use IEditableObject on your "model" to handle the commit of changes in a transactional way.

- http://www.paulstovell.com/editable-object-adapter