# Bind command in WPF using MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I am learning **MVVM** and **WPF**. I have a `xaml` file in my project and which has a simple click event handler in the code behind.

Now I want to do the same in **MVVM**. I read a lot of articles and also read many answers in sof. But still unable to do this.

Can anyone please give a simple example in which a button **click** event is done in **MVVM**.

**Edit**

```
<Window x:Class="WhiteBalance.BaseCalWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:NumberUpDownControl;assembly=NumberUpDownControl"
        xmlns:viewn="clr-namespace:WhiteBalance.ViewModels"
        Title="RefImgSettingWindow"  Height="900" Width="1000" ResizeMode="NoResize" 
        BorderThickness="4">
    <Window.Resources>
        <viewn:DashBoardViewModel x:Key="demokey"></viewn:DashBoardViewModel>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="gdParent" DataContext="{StaticResource demokey}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="490" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="488*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="300" />
            <RowDefinition Height="300" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=NAME,Mode=TwoWay}" Height="28" Name="lblTest" />
            <Button Content="Capture" Height="23" Name="btnCapture" Width="75" Command="{Binding Path=SaveCommand}"
                             Canvas.Left="94" Canvas.Top="254" />

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>

namespace WhiteBalance.ViewModels
{
    public class DashBoardViewModel: ObservableObject
    {
        private string _name = "dsqdasd";

        public string NAME
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        public ICommand SaveCommand
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        private bool CanExecuteSaveCommand()
        {
            return true;    // !string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName);
        }

        private void CreateSaveCommand()
        {
            SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveExecute, CanExecuteSaveCommand);
        }

        public void SaveExecute()
        {
            //Person.Save(_newPerson);
            NAME = "Changed Name";
        }

        public DashBoardViewModel()
        {
            //objModel.TestText = "This will change";
            NAME = "TestName";
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using any MVVM framework? What have you tried?

Comment: Is it mandatory to use MVVM framework? I am not aware of any framework. The only thing I got is I need to use ICommand but how to use this and what changes is needed in ViewModel, I don't know.

Comment: No, but it helps A LOT, I'd recommend MVVM Light http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can bind the [Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.command%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property of the button to any property that returns [ICommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) implements a nice convenient command called [DelegateCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg431410%28v=pandp.39%29.aspx) that is very easy to use ([here is a knock-off](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html) of it):

```
public ICommand MyButtonClickCommand 
{
    get { return new DelegateCommand<object>(FuncToCall, FuncToEvaluate); }
}

private void FuncToCall(object context)
{
    //this is called when the button is clicked
}

private bool FuncToEvaluate(object context)
{
    //this is called to evaluate whether FuncToCall can be called
    //for example you can return true or false based on some validation logic
    return true;
}



<Button x:Name="myButton" Command="{Binding MyButtonClickCommand}" />
```

The CodeProject example [*How to use Commands in WPF*](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238657/How-to-use-Commands-in-WPF) has a very similar example with code that you can easily work through. The previous Stack Overflow question has an example using RoutedCommands that are statically bound to: [*How to bind Close command to a button*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065887/how-to-bind-close-command-to-a-button), and [*How to bind WPF button to a command in ViewModelBase?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422945/how-to-bind-wpf-button-to-a-command-in-viewmodelbase) has a slightly more advanced example.

Comment: Thanks @slugster. Is DelegateCommand is a system defined class or do I need to create this? I am checking the links provided by you.

Comment: @Narendra It's defined in the Prism libraries, you just need to reference them, or look at the link to the knock-off version.

Comment: I have added the recent changes in question. Can you please tell why it is not calling the required function?

Comment: @Narendra From what I can see you never call `CreateSaveCommand()` so the value of `SaveCommand` will be null.

Answer (score 5):

Seeing a lot of answers implementing this ICommand interface, I suggest a simpler option, which is to use the built in `System.Windows.Input`

Here's an example:

Xaml View:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Class="SomeDialog"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" 
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">

    <StackPanel>
        <Button Width="Auto" Command="{Binding ClearCommand}" Content="Clear"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

View Code behind:

```
using System.Windows;

public partial class SomeDialog : Window
{
    public SomeDialog()
    {
        var vm = new ViewModel();
        DataContext = vm;
        CommandBindings.AddRange(vm.Commands);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
 }
```

View model:

```
using System.Windows.Input;

public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    readonly CommandBindingCollection commands = new CommandBindingCollection();

    public static RoutedUICommand ClearCommand { get; set; } = new RoutedUICommand("Clear", "ClearCommand", typeof(ErrorDialog));

    public CommandBindingCollection Commands
    {
        get
        {
            commands.Add(new CommandBinding(ClearCommand, OnClearExecuted);
            return commands;
        }
    }

    void OnClearExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        view.DialogResult = true; //Indicate things
        view.Close(); //Close the window
    }
}
```

Call like this:

```
public void OpenSomeDialog()
{
    var dialog = new SomeDialog() {Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow};
    bool? b = dialog.ShowDialog();
    if (b != null && (bool) b)
        //Do things
}
```

*Now go dialog things.*

Comment: Such a great answer. I upvoted and I'm using in my solution with the little improvement binding the button text to the RoutedUICommand.Text property: `<Button Command="{Binding ClearCommand}" Content="{Binding ClearCommand.Text}"/>`

Comment: There's a problem with your example. In the `ViewModel` class, every time the `Commands` property is retrieved, a new `CommandBinding` for the `ClearCommand` will be added to the `commands` collection. The code should only add the `CommandBinding` to the collection once upon instantiation.