# How to bind a ContextMenu's click handler to a function

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I've got some XAML like the following:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Foo">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu1">
      <MenuItem Header="Command 1a"/>
      <MenuItem Header="Command 1b"/>
    </ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu2">
      <MenuItem Header="Command 2a"/>
      <MenuItem Header="Command 2b"/>
    </ContextMenu>
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <DockPanel>
    <TreeView>
      <TreeView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Type1}">
          <StackPanel ContextMenu="{StaticResource ContextMenu1"}/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Type2}">
          <StackPanel ContextMenu="{StaticResource ContextMenu2"}/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
  </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

and a code behind similar to the following:

```
public class Type1 {
  public void OnCommand1a() {}
  public void OnCommand1b() {}
}

public class Type2 {
  public void OnCommand2a() {}
  public void OnCommand2b() {}
}
```

What do I need to do so that clicking the respective items on the menus calls the corresponding function?

If I add:

```
Command="{Binding Path=OnCommand1a}" CommandTarget="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget}"
```

etc then at runtime I get errors about how OnCommand1a is not a property.  Some searching suggests this has something to do with a RoutedUIEvent, but I don't really understand what that's about.

If I use

```
Click="OnCommand1a"
```

then it looks for OnCommand1a() on the UserControl instead of on the type that is bound to the DataTemplate.

What is the standard way of dealing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314828/bind-command-in-wpf-using-mvvm, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422945/how-to-bind-wpf-button-to-a-command-in-viewmodelbase, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531772/binding-button-click-to-a-method Follow these link to know about Command Binding and make use of that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need a class that extends ICommand.
You can use this:

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> executeMethod = null;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> canExecuteMethod = null;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { return; }
        remove { return; } 
    }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> executeMethod, Func<object, bool> canExecuteMethod)
    {
        this.executeMethod = executeMethod;
        this.canExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (canExecuteMethod == null) return true;
        return this.canExecuteMethod(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (executeMethod == null) return;
        this.executeMethod(parameter);
    }
}
```

Then, in your class Type1 you have to declare this:

```
public DelegateCommand OnCommand1a {get; private set;}
```

and set it in your Type1 constructor in this way:

```
OnCommand1a = new DelegateCommand(c => Cmd1a(), null);
```

where Cmd1a is:

```
private void Cmd1a()
{
     //your code here
}
```

Finally, in your xaml:

```
Command="{Binding Path=OnCommand1a}"
```