# How can i get selected item(s) and events from ListView with Caliburn.Micro in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I wrote a program with MVVM (C#) and XAML using Caliburn.Micro library, how can i:

- get **all** selected items (not only one item)?
- get selected change event?
- sort items by clicking header columns?

Any help would be appreciated.

GUI code: **Views \ MainView.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="ListBox_CaliburnMicro.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ListBox_CaliburnMicro"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="600">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <vm:MainViewModel/>
        </Grid.DataContext>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="153*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Command="{Binding HelloCommand}" Content="Hello ..." HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" ToolTip="Test" Background="White" Foreground="Black" Height="22" />
        <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" ToolTip="Add item end of list" Background="White" Foreground="Black" Height="22"/>
        <Button Content="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="96,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" ToolTip="Delete first item from list" Background="White" Foreground="Black" Height="22"/>
        <Button Content="Update" Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="184,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" ToolTip="Update first item from list" Background="White" Foreground="Black" Height="22"/>
        <Button Content="GetSelectedItem" Command="{Binding GetSelectedItemCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="271,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="95" ToolTip="get selected item from list" Background="White" Foreground="Black" Height="22"/>
        <Button Content="GetItem:" Command="{Binding GetItemXCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="377,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" ToolTip="get item x, from list" Background="White" Foreground="Black" Height="22"/>

        <TextBox x:Name="ItemX" Text="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="455,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70"/>

        <TextBlock x:Name="OuputText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="165,40,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="415" Foreground="#FFFF0909"/>
        <Label Content="Output:"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="100,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="55"/>

        <ListView Grid.Column="1" x:Name="FileListView" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Files}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,65,10,10" Foreground="Black" Background="#FFE6EEF7">

            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="Auto"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileStatus}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="Auto"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Size" Width="Auto"
                     DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileSize}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="System Type" Width="Auto"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileType}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Email Count" Width="Auto"
                     DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileEmailCount}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Info Count" Width="Auto"
                     DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileInfoCount}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>

        </ListView>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel code: **ViewModels \ MainViewModel.cs**

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using ListBox_CaliburnMicro.Model;
using ListBox_CaliburnMicro.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ListBox_CaliburnMicro
{
    public class MainViewModel : Screen, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            FillDataFile();

            HelloCommand = new RelayCommand(DoHello, CanDoHello);
            AddCommand = new RelayCommand(DoAdd, CanDoAdd);
            DeleteCommand = new RelayCommand(DoDelete, CanDoDelete);
            UpdateCommand = new RelayCommand(DoUpdate, CanDoUpdate);
            GetSelectedItemCommand = new RelayCommand(DoGetSelectedItem, CanDoGetSelectedItem);
            GetItemXCommand = new RelayCommand(DoGetGetItemX, CanDoGetItemX);
        }

        #region File listView
        private ObservableCollection<File> _Files;
        public ObservableCollection<File> Files
        {
            get { return _Files; }
            set
            {
                _Files = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Files");
            }
        }

        private void FillDataFile()
        {

            _Files = new ObservableCollection<File>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                string strName = string.Format("{0}", i);
                _Files.Add(new File() { FileStatus = "status", FileName = strName, FileSize = i, FileType = "type", FileEmailCount = "email_count", FileInfoCount = "info_count" });
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion

        #region OuputText textbox
        private string _OuputText = "-";
        public string OuputText
        {
            get
            {
                return _OuputText;
            }
            set
            {
                _OuputText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("OuputText");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region ItemX textbox
        private string _ItemX = "0";
        public string ItemX
        {
            get
            {
                return _ItemX;
            }
            set
            {
                int nItem = 0;
                if (Int32.TryParse(value, out nItem))
                {
                    if (nItem >= _Files.Count || nItem < 0)
                        return;
                }

                _ItemX = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ItemX");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region command button

        #region Hello button
        public RelayCommand HelloCommand { get; set; }
        private bool CanDoHello(object obj)
        {
            return true;
        }
        private void DoHello(object obj)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("DoHello");
        }
        #endregion

        #region Add button
        public RelayCommand AddCommand { get; set; }
        private bool CanDoAdd(object obj)
        {
            return true;
        }
        private void DoAdd(object obj)
        {
            string strName = string.Format("{0}", _Files.Count + 1);
            _Files.Add(new File() { FileStatus = "status", FileName = strName, FileSize = _Files.Count, FileType = "type", FileEmailCount = "email_count", FileInfoCount = "info_count" });
        }
        #endregion

        #region Delete button
        public RelayCommand DeleteCommand { get; set; }
        private bool CanDoDelete(object obj)
        {
            if (_Files.Count > 0)
                return true;

            return false;
        }
        private void DoDelete(object obj)
        {
            if (_Files.Count > 0)
            {
                if (SelectedItem != null)
                    _Files.Remove(SelectedItem);
                else
                    _Files.RemoveAt(0);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Update button
        public RelayCommand UpdateCommand { get; set; }
        private bool CanDoUpdate(object obj)
        {
            if (_Files.Count > 0)
                return true;

            return false;
        }
        private void DoUpdate(object obj)
        {
            // var vvv= SelectedItems;


            if (_Files.Count > 0)
            {
                if (SelectedItem != null)
                    SelectedItem.FileName = "Updated ..."; // change FileName field
                else
                    _Files[0].FileName = "Updated ...";
            }

            // List<File> FilesSelect = _Files.Where(p => p.FileID == _Files[0].FileID).ToList();
        }
        #endregion

        #region GetSelectedItem button
        public RelayCommand GetSelectedItemCommand { get; set; }
        private bool CanDoGetSelectedItem(object obj)
        {
            if (_Files.Count > 0)
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        public File SelectedItem { get; set; }
        public int SelectedIndex { get; set; }
        private void DoGetSelectedItem(object obj)
        {
            if (_Files.Count > 0 && SelectedItem != null)
            {
                var selected_file = SelectedItem;

                OuputText = string.Format("first selected index {0} -> [{1}]", SelectedIndex, selected_file.FileID);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region GetItemX button
        public RelayCommand GetItemXCommand { get; set; }
        private bool CanDoGetItemX(object obj)
        {
            if (_Files.Count > 0)
                return true;

            return false;
        }
        private void DoGetGetItemX(object obj)
        {
            int nItem = 0;
            if (Int32.TryParse(ItemX, out nItem))
            {
                if (nItem < _Files.Count)
                {
                    OuputText = string.Format("select index {0} -> [{1}]", nItem, _Files[nItem].FileID);
                }
            }
            else
                OuputText = "-";
        }
        #endregion

        #endregion
    }
}
```

ICommand code: **ViewModels \ RelayCommand.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ListBox_CaliburnMicro.ViewModels
{
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        #region field
        readonly Action<object> _execute;
        readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
        #endregion

        #region constructors
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null)
        {

        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("execute");

            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }
        #endregion

        #region member
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }
        #endregion

        #region raise
        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            /*if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
                CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);*/
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Model code: **Model \ File.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ListBox_CaliburnMicro.Model
{
    public class File : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Guid _FileID;
        public Guid FileID
        {
            get
            {
                return _FileID;
            }
            set 
            {
                _FileID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FileID");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private string _FileStatus;
        public string FileStatus
        {
            get
            {
                return _FileStatus;
            }
            set
            {
                _FileStatus = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FileStatus");
            }
        }

        private string _FileName;
        public string FileName
        {
            get
            {
                return _FileName;
            }
            set
            {
                _FileName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FileName");
            }
        }

        public int _FileSize;
        public int FileSize
        {
            get
            {
                return _FileSize;
            }
            set
            {
                _FileSize = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FileSize");
            }
        }

        private string _FileType;
        public string FileType
        {
            get
            {
                return _FileType;
            }
            set
            {
                _FileType = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FileType");
            }
        }

        private string _FileEmailCount;
        public string FileEmailCount
        {
            get
            {
                return _FileEmailCount;
            }
            set
            {
                _FileEmailCount = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FileEmailCount");
            }
        }

        private string _FileInfoCount;
        public string FileInfoCount
        {
            get
            {
                return _FileInfoCount;
            }
            set
            {
                _FileInfoCount = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FileInfoCount");
            }
        }

        public File()
        {
            FileID = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
        public File(string s1 = "", string s2 = "", int s3 = 0, string s4 = "", string s5 = "", string s6 = "")
        {
            FileID = Guid.NewGuid();

            FileStatus = s1;
            FileName = s2;
            FileSize = s3;
            FileType = s4;
            FileEmailCount = s5;
            FileInfoCount = s6;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is better to ask one question per a  topic. For example, **question1:** get all selected items (not only one item)? **question2:** get selected change event? **question3:**  sort items by clicking header columns?
it is a real separation of concerns and you'll get more exact and wider answers, and you will attract more people than by one question

Answer (score 0):

You have to hook up these events to a command and process them in the viewmodel.

Not using Caliburn.Micro but there should also be a concept for EventToCommand Binding. I quick search revealed the following links.

https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Cheat%20Sheet

https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions

http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/01/24/caliburn-micro-part-3-more-about-events-and-parameters/

if I did not get your question correct please let me know...

HTH

Comment: Thank you @silverfighter, but my question exactly was: how can i: - get all selected items (not only one item)?
- get selected change event?
- sort items by clicking header columns?