# How can i get all selected item(s) from ListView in ViewModel class?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I wrote a program with MVVM (C#) and XAML using Caliburn.Micro library, how can I get **all** selected items from ListView control (not only one item)?

[My code link ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35283807/how-can-i-get-selected-items-and-events-from-listview-with-caliburn-micro-in-c/35290461#35290461)

With binding method `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"` just got first selected item!

Comment: You might find your solution theire http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831918/how-to-get-all-checked-items-from-a-listview

Comment: @Templum None of answers were based on MVVM in the link provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get selected items into the ViewModel, first create a property of `bool` type in your model that will be bound with `IsSelected` property of `ListViewItem`.

**Property in Model class:**

```
 public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set 
        { 
            isSelected = value;
            RaiseChange("IsSelected");
        }
    }
```

**XAML Style:**

```
 <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

**Final Property in ViewModel:**

```
 public List<DataGridItem> SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return list.Where(item=>item.IsSelected).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't get selected items with (control+a) !!! -and- how can i get key pressed in ListView?

Comment: @mohammadmot use keydown event.

Answer (score 1):

Keep calm and see example on github :)
https://github.com/samueldjack/SelectedItemsBindingDemo/blob/master/MultiSelectorBehaviours.cs

This example based on using behaviours.
It is powerfull approach which can resolve many problem in MVVM.

You need 3 files from example: ***IListeItemConverter.cs, MultiSelectorBehaviour.cs, TwoListSynchronizer.cs***. Copy it to your project.

then you must define namespace in your view

```
xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:[MultiSelectorBehavourNamespace]"
```

after it you can use MultiSelectorBehaviour in ListView

```
<ListView DockPanel.Dock="Top" conv:MultiSelectorBehaviours.SynchronizedSelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems}"/>
```

course you need also define SourceItems property in your ViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<YourItemType> selectedItems = new ObservableCollection<YourItemType>();
    public ObservableCollection<YourItemType> SelectedItems
    {
        get { return selectedItems; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedItems != value)
            {
                selectedItems = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedItems);
            }
        }
    }
```