# Select All items in ListView with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to select all **Items** in a **ListView**, using mvvm. Using code-behind, I have tried **SelectAll()** and **foreach** to select them, but I would like to use MVVM like the rest of my project. Any ideas?

Here is the listview:

```
<ListView x:Name="TransformerList"  ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentStations}" Margin="16,250,0,10.4" SelectionMode="Multiple" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="411">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Select">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SeeAllCustomersCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding Item1}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedCustomersChangedCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}" />
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=TransformerIsSelected}" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Nettstasjon" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Område" Width="210" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Area}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Radial" Width="110" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Radial}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

and the button:

```
public ICommand cmd_VelgAlle { get { return new RelayCommand(on_cmd_VelgAlle);  } }
    private void on_cmd_VelgAlle()
    {
        foreach (item i in CurrentStations) //the item here gives an error "type or namespace could not be found"
        {
            i.TransformerIsSelected = true;
        }
    }
```

And the mvvm:

```
private bool _TransformerIsSelected;
    public bool TransformerIsSelected
    {
        get { return _TransformerIsSelected; }
        set
        {
            _TransformerIsSelected = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("TransformerIsSelected");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Bind `ListViewItem.IsSelected` to some bool property in your item view model and change that property for all items to true

Comment: I have answered this question here: [Select items in listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35339524/how-can-i-get-all-selected-items-from-listview-in-viewmodel-class/35340701#35340701)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a `ListViewItem` `Style`:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Create a property in `Model` class:

```
public bool IsSelected
{
    get { return isSelected; }
    set 
    { 
        isSelected = value;
        RaiseChange("IsSelected");
    }
}
```

And iterate your ItemSource to set `IsSelected` `true` for all items.(***In ViewModel***)

```
foreach(item i in yourCollection)
{
    i.IsSelected = true;
}
```

**Update:**

Use Style as:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">                
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=TransformerIsSelected}" />
        </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Command:

```
 private void on_cmd_VelgAlle()
    {
        //Item is the class your CurrentStations is made of(i guess something like `station` in your design)
        //i.e if CurrentStations is list of string then Item will be string
        foreach (Item i in CurrentStations) 
        {
            i.TransformerIsSelected = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am currently trying to implement this, but I am having issues with the foreach. I cannot seem to get item to work. And yourCollection will not work whatever I put in there. Should I put the x:Name from XAML or the ItemSource? Any tips?

Comment: @Thomas YourCollection is the itemSource of your listView. Also have you created IsSelected property in your Model class(i.e whichever class your collection is made of)

Comment: I'll edit the question to contain some code so you can see :) Thanks again for helping.

Comment: @Thomas If you are getting compile time error cause of 'item' than see my updated answer. also change the ItemContainerStyle as well as mentioned in the answer update. :)