# WPF window buttons (close, max, min, restore) binding to system command fails

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

### EDIT

I've corrected the binding issue as quoted in the Output Window:

> System.Windows.Data Information: 41 : BindingExpression path error: 'Source{x:Static SystemCommands' property not found for 'object' because data item is null. This could happen because the data provider has not produced any data yet. BindingExpression:Path=Source{x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name='Close'); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

I'd missed a `=` between Source and {

This was mentioned in every line of the output window as quoted below, however fixing this has not corrected the problem that ***the buttons still do nothing.***

The Output Window is now chock full of the following, all referencing controls that are not my window buttons:

> System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=Source{x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name='Close'); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

---

### ORIGINAL QUESTION

Based on a few answers on SO, I've built the following buttons to close, maximize, restore and minimize my window:

```
<!--Close Button-->
<Button x:Name="Close" Style="{StaticResource TitleButton}"
        Command="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
    <Grid Width="30" Height="25">
        <Path x:Name="Cross" Data="M0,0 L1,1 M0,1 L1,0" Stretch="Fill" Width="8" Height="8"
              Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" StrokeThickness="2" />
    </Grid>
</Button>

<!--Maximize Button-->
<Button x:Name="Maximize" Style="{StaticResource TitleButton}"
        Command="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemCommands.MaximizeWindowCommand}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" >
    <Grid Width="30" Height="25">
        <Path Data="M0,1 L9,1 L9,8 L0,8 Z" Width="9" Height="8" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" StrokeThickness="2"  />
    </Grid>
</Button>

<!--Restore Button-->
<Button x:Name="Restore" Visibility="Collapsed" Style="{StaticResource TitleButton}"
        Command="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemCommands.RestoreWindowCommand}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
    <Grid Width="30" Height="25" UseLayoutRounding="True" RenderTransform="1,0,0,1,.5,.5">
        <Path Data="M2,0 L8,0 L8,6 M0,3 L6,3 M0,2 L6,2 L6,8 L0,8 Z" Width="8" Height="8" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" StrokeThickness="1"  />
    </Grid>
</Button>

<!--Minimize Button-->
<Button x:Name="Minimize" Style="{StaticResource TitleButton}"
        Command="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
    <Grid Width="30" Height="25">
        <Path Data="M9,0 L8,1 8,1 8,1 0,1 0,1 z" Width="9" Height="9" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" StrokeThickness="2" />
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

I've checked the bindings with some other developers who are more knowledgeable and they say the bindings look fine but maybe I need a namespace. They had to go before they were able to clarify.

The Output Window in Visual Studio shows the following errors (paradoxically, all seem to be relevant to the **Close Window Button** which is the only one that has it's style `TitleButton` working on it.

Seems like there's some sort of data binding problem here which is strange since I obviously don't need to bind these to data... I did find a few answers on SO but all seem to deal with other things:

- [How to hide wpf datagrid columns depending on a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857780/how-to-hide-wpf-datagrid-columns-depending-on-a-property/6858917#6858917)
- [ElementName Binding is failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122592/elementname-binding-is-failing)

> System.Windows.Data Information: 41 : BindingExpression path error: 'Source{x:Static SystemCommands' property not found for 'object' because data item is null.  This could happen because the data provider has not produced any data yet. BindingExpression:Path=Source{x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name='Close'); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
>
> System.Windows.Data Information: 20 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value due to missing information. BindingExpression:Path=Source{x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name='Close'); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
>
> System.Windows.Data Information: 21 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value from null data item. This could happen when binding is detached or when binding to a Nullable type that has no value. BindingExpression:Path=Source{x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name='Close'); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
>
> System.Windows.Data Information: 20 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value due to missing information. BindingExpression:Path=Source{x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name='Close'); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
>
> System.Windows.Data Information: 21 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value from null data item. This could happen when binding is detached or when binding to a Nullable type that has no value. BindingExpression:Path=Source{x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name='Close'); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
>
> System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=Source{x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name='Close'); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Answer (score 1):

When using the static routed commands found in the static SystemCommands class you do not need to use a Binding and can instead simplify your xaml to the following.

Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand}"

Comment: I see that's drastically reduced the amount of messages that I mentioned in the edit so I'll +1 your answer but the buttons still don't work. Its like they're completely non-interactive.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. I'm not sure what your xaml structure is but the button invokes the commands and you need to implement a CommandBinding on a control that you want to handle the command. Typically for these types of commands you would place these on a window. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065887/how-to-bind-close-command-to-a-button