# Bind ViewModel method to View's Alt+F4 and Close button

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have created a custom method to close a form in my view model and bound it to a button. How do I get the default close button in the title bar and <kbd>Alt+F4</kbd> to run the same command?

```
public void Close(object parameter)
{
    // Check if any field has been edited
    if (IsDirty())
    {
        string message = "You have unsaved changes.\n\nAre you sure you want to close this form?";
        string title = "Close Window";
        MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(message, title, MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Warning, MessageBoxResult.Cancel);

        if (result == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
            return;
    }

    employeeWindow.Close();
}
```

I'm still new to WPF and MVVM, and I'm just not understanding any of the solutions already out there or how I can customise them to run the above code.

Comment: [WPF window close button binding](https://www.google.com/search?q=wpf+window+close+button+binding+site:stackoverflow.com&client=firefox-b-d&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjk-bSen9HuAhVtwIsKHd_BBXQQrQIoBHoECAUQBQ&biw=1920&bih=966)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind Close command to a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065887/how-to-bind-close-command-to-a-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`Closing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.closing?view=net-5.0) event on [`Window`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window?view=net-5.0). Its [`CancelEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs?view=net-5.0) carry a [`Cancel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel?view=net-5.0#System_ComponentModel_CancelEventArgs_Cancel) property of type `bool` that can be set to `true`, which will cancel closing the window. The closing event will both be fired for closing a window using the close button and pressing <kbd>Alt+F4</kbd>.

### Code-Behind

In a code-behind scenario, you would add an event handler in XAML like this.

```
<Window Closing="OnClosing" ...>
```

Then, you would create this event handler in code-behind and set the `Cancel` property accordingly.

```
private void OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
   // Check if any field has been edited
   if (IsDirty())
   {
      string message = "You have unsaved changes.\n\nAre you sure you want to close this form?";
      string title = "Close Window";
      MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(message, title, MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Warning, MessageBoxResult.Cancel);

      if (result == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
         e.Cancel = true;
   }
}
```

### Event Trigger (Non MVVM)

In MVVM you could install the *[Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/)* NuGet package, which is a replacement of the legacy Blend behaviors (`System.Windows.Interactivity`). You can use an `EventTrigger` to bind the event to a command in your view model. In this example, you pass the `CancelEventArgs` directly to the command.

```
<Window ...>
   <b:Interaction.Triggers>
      <b:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
         <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ClosingCommand}"
                                PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
      </b:EventTrigger>
   </b:Interaction.Triggers>
   <!-- ...other markup. -->
</Window>
```

This solution allows you to define a command in your view model.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public MyViewModel()
   {
      ClosingCommand = new RelayCommand<CancelEventArgs>(ExecuteClosing);
   }

   public ICommand ClosingCommand { get; }

private void ExecuteClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
   {
      string message = "You have unsaved changes.\n\nAre you sure you want to close this form?";
      string title = "Close Window";
      MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(message, title, MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Warning, MessageBoxResult.Cancel);
   
      if (result == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
         e.Cancel = true;
   }
}
```

I do not provide an `ICommand` implementation here. For more information on the basics refer to:

- [MVVM - Commands, RelayCommands and EventToCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/may/mvvm-commands-relaycommands-and-eventtocommand)

Although this solution uses a command on the view model, it is not MVVM compliant, since the message box is a view component that must not reside in a view model. The same applies to the cancel event args.

### MVVM Behavior

An MVVM compliant way could be to create a behavior to move the confirmation code out. For that create an interface for your view model that contains the `IsDirty` method and implement it in your view model.

```
public interface IStatefulViewModel
{
   bool IsDirty();
}
```

```
public class MyViewModel : IStatefulViewModel
{
   // ...your code.

   public bool IsDirty()
   {
      // ...your checks.
   }
}
```

Then, create a behavior using the *[Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/)* NuGet package. This behavior is reusable and encapsulates the closing logic decoupled from your view model. The `Caption` and `Message` dependency properties allow binding the message box contents.

```
public class WindowClosingBehavior : Behavior<Window>
{
   public static readonly DependencyProperty CaptionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      nameof(Caption), typeof(string), typeof(WindowClosingBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

   public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      nameof(Message), typeof(string), typeof(WindowClosingBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

   public string Caption
   {
      get => (string)GetValue(CaptionProperty);
      set => SetValue(CaptionProperty, value);
   }

   public string Message
   {
      get => (string)GetValue(MessageProperty);
      set => SetValue(MessageProperty, value);
   }

   protected override void OnAttached()
   {
      base.OnAttached();
      AssociatedObject.Closing += OnClosing;
   }

   protected override void OnDetaching()
   {
      base.OnDetaching();
      AssociatedObject.Closing -= OnClosing;
   }

   private void OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
   {
      if (!(AssociatedObject.DataContext is IStatefulViewModel statefulViewModel))
         return;

      if (!statefulViewModel.IsDirty())
         return;

      e.Cancel = ConfirmClosing();
   }

   private bool ConfirmClosing()
   {
      var result = MessageBox.Show(
         Message,
         Caption,
         MessageBoxButton.OKCancel,
         MessageBoxImage.Warning,
         MessageBoxResult.Cancel);

      return result == MessageBoxResult.Cancel;
   }
}
```

Attach the behavior to your window. Note that you can do this on any window.

```
<Window ...>
   <b:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <local:WindowClosingBehavior Caption="Close Window"
                                   Message="You have unsaved changes.&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;Are you sure you want to close this form?"/>
   </b:Interaction.Behaviors>
   <!-- ...other markup. -->
</Window>
```

Do not be confused by the `&#13;&#10;` characters, those are newlines (`\n`) in XML.

Comment: Brilliant, that's everything that I'm after, I followed your MVVM Behaviour one.  And thank you for explaining them.

Comment: What do you mean by 'message box is a view component that must not reside in a view model'.  My view is created by the view model, because if the view model fails to load the employee from the database I don't want the view to be created or shown.  Is this not MVVM compliant?

Comment: @smally MVVM is about spearating your user interface from the business logic. This implies that you must not have any view component references in your view model, be it a `Window`, a `UserControl` or any other control. So no, this is not MVVM compliant.